# Python: how to call multiple super __new__ with multiple inheritance?

Tags: python

I have 2 classes: `A` and `B`, both of them instantiated by `__new__` with different set of arguments (like `a` for `A`, and `foo, bar` for `B`). Now I want to implement class `C`, inherited from `A` and `B`, and instantiate it with 3 args: `a, foo, bar`, passing correspondent arguments to super classes `__new__`, but things goes wrong from here.

If we have no arguments I just call `super(C, cls).__new__()` and object of class `C` successfully created (it calls both `A.__new__()` and `B.__new__()` and combines it somehow). But how to do it 'by hands'? So I want to pass `a` to `A.__new__`, `foo, bar` to `B.__new__` and combine somehow returned instances (is this right way to get object of class `C` at the end?).

Anyway I can't do both.

Fist - calling `A.__new__` raises incorrect number of arguments exception in `o = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)` in `A.__new__()` (but `A` can be instantiated as standalone)

Second - I have no idea how to combine even successfully instantiated object of classes `A` and `B` into object of class `C`.

So could please someone to explain what is going on here?

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, a):
        o = super(A, cls).__new__(cls)
        setattr(o, 'a', a)
        return o

class B(object):
    def __new__(cls, foo, bar):
        o = super(B, cls).__new__(cls)
        setattr(o, 'foo', foo)
        setattr(o, 'bar', bar)
        return o

print A(1) # ok, <__main__.A object at 0x00000000022F1630>
print B(2,3) # ok, <__main__.B object at 0x00000000022F1630>


class C(A,B):
    def __new__(cls, a, foo, bar):
        o1 = A.__new__(cls, a) #fail - exception while calling super.new in A
        o2 = B.__new__(cls, foo, bar)  #fail - exception while calling super.new in A
        # return # What? How to combine o1 o2 even if they are created succesfuly?
        # # return super(C, cls).__new__(cls, ?????)

print C(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Why using `__new__`?  If it's just setting attributes, do this with `__init__`..

Comment: first, I'd like to understand how to deal with `__new__` methods, second - it's not always just setting attributes

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov The spirit of what you're asking, for cases more complex than attribute manipulation, is the task of instance creation with `__new__` in a custom metaclass. But by definition in Python, a class must have only one metaclass, it cannot have multiple metaclasses the same way that a class can have multiple bases. You still could have a *sequence* of inheritance for metaclasses, just not anything like a mixin pattern (and generally shouldn't want to).

Comment: @ely Sorry, is it possible to ask you to write some code to illustrate metaclass concept usage in this case? Which single inheritance it's all clear, what to do with multiply?

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov "multiple metaclasses" is not permitted, which means there is no analog of "multiple inheritance" (of which mixin is a special type) when you're talking about metaclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `__new__` is what creates your instance, you *should not* call `super(...).__new__` multiple times as it would create multiple instances.

What you want to do it use `__init__` which initializes your already created instance.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, foo, bar):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, foo, bar)
```

In particular, I want to point out that it is not true that on multiple inheritance Python will call both `A.__new__` and`B.__new__` and "combine somehow". Have a look at this code

```
class A(object):
    def __new__(*args):
        print('A.__new__ was called')
        return type(*args) # This is what ultimately creates every object in Python

class B(object):
    def __new__(*args):
        print('B.__new__ was called')
        return type(*args)

# As expected the following is printed when instances are created
a = A() # Prints 'A.__new__ was called'
b = B() # Prints 'B.__new__ was called'

class C(A, B):
    pass

c = C() # Prints 'A.__new__ was called'
```

So we observe that `B.__new__` was never called. On multiple inheritance, Python will inherit the method from the [left-most class that has this method](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). In this case, `C` inherited `A.__new__`.

Comment: Sorry, It's clear about `__init__`, but how to make same tricks with `__new__`? Just abstract from creating attributes, it's just for illustration. It's not part of question. I just like to understand more deep internal machinery under the `__new__` concept. In common: we know how to instantiate class A, we know how to instantiate class B, how to instantiate C, which is inherited from A and B?

Comment: `__new__` is not meant to be used this way.

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov Here you have an example of how multiple inheritance works. It is not true that both method are called.

Comment: I mean if define `__new__` in C and call single `super().__new__` - it will call _both_ A and B `__new__`

Comment: No, it will only call `A.__new__`, `super()` recovers its methods from the left-most superclass in the [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). `super().some_method` will never somehow "merge" two methods together, there is just no way to do this in general. Multiple inheritance can be tricky, I recommend you read a bit more about it (see MRO link above) before using it.

Comment: Please check the [code](https://github.com/AntonOvsyannikov/PyStuff/blob/master/1.py). It outputs `C.__new__ >>> A.__new__ B.__new__ <<<` where `>> <<` surrounds _single_ `super.__new__`

Comment: Ok... what is happening is that `C.__mro__` is `[C, A, B, object]`. So when you called `super(C, cls).__new__`, you ended up in `A.__new__`, but since you are in the context of `C`, it is `C` you are passing as `cls` to `super(A, cls).__new__` thus it still uses `C.__mro__` and thus call `B.__new__`. In no case does `C.__new__` calls both `A.__new__` and `B.__new__`, it is you by calling `super(A, cls).__new__` who is calling `B.__new__`. Yea... [Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) can be complex sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `return super().__new__(cls)` in `__new__` of derived class.

See following code snippet:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('A new')
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
class B:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('B new')
        return super().__new__(cls)  
        
class C(A, B):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('D new')
        return super().__new__(cls)
        
        
c = C()
print([isinstance(c, cls) for cls in [A, B, C]])
```

Output:

```
D new
A new
B new
[True, True, True]
```